# What is AttributeError: '_tkinter.tkapp' object has no attribute 'sizeNotifier'

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

````
class App(ctk.CTk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(fg_color=WHITE)
        self.title('SQL Connector')
        self._set_appearance_mode('dark')
        self.geometry('600x400')
        self.minsize(400, 300)
        # self.maxsize(800, 800)
        self.columnconfigure(index=(0, 1, 2, 3, 4), weight=1, uniform='a')
        self.rowconfigure(index=(0, 1, 2, 3, 4), weight=1, uniform='b')
        self.minsize(400, 300)

        # Data
        self.entryVar = ctk.StringVar()
        self.labelVar = ctk.StringVar(value='SQL Connector')

        # widgets
        self.entry = Entry(self, entryVar=self.entryVar)
        self.entry.grid(row=2, column=1, columnspan=3)
        self.button = Button(self, 'press For Commands')
        self.button.grid(row=2, column=1, columnspan=3, rowspan=2, pady=10)
        SlidePanelButton(self).grid(row=3, column=1, columnspan=3)

        self.slider = SlidePanel(parent=self, startPos=0, endPos=-0.3)
        self.slider.place()

        # event binding
        try:
            self.entry.bind('<Return>', self.entryBinding)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)

        # threshold values for window
        try:
            self.sizeNotifier = SizeNotifier(
                self,
                {
                    300: self.sizeNotifier.create_small_layout(),
                    600: self.sizeNotifier.create_medium_layout(),
                    1200: self.sizeNotifier.createLargeLayout()
                }
            )
            # self.bind('<Configure>', lambda event:self.responsiveWindow(event = event))
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)

    def entryBinding(self):
        self.button.executeCmds()

    def responsiveWindow(self, event):
        # window attributes
        self.windowWidth = event.width
        self.windowHeight = event.height

        if (self.windowWidth >= 600 and self.windowHeight <= 600):
            self.button.grid(row=2, column=1, columnspan=3, rowspan=2)
            self.entry.grid(row=2, column=1, columnspan=3)
            SlidePanelButton(self).grid(row=3, column=1, columnspan=3)
            print(self.windowWidth, self.windowHeight)
        else:
            self.button.grid(row=1, column=1, columnspan=3, rowspan=2)
            self.entry.grid(row=2, column=1, columnspan=3)
            SlidePanelButton(self).grid(row=3, column=1, columnspan=3)```

Size notifier object

import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


class SizeNotifier:
    def __init__(self, window, size_dict):
        self.window = window
        self.size_dict = {key: value for key, value in sorted(size_dict.items())}
        self.current_min_size = None
        self.window.bind('<Configure>', self.check_size)

        self.window.update()

        min_height = self.window.winfo_height()
        min_width = list(self.size_dict)[0]
        self.window.minsize(min_width, min_height)

    def check_size(self, event):
        if event.widget == self.window:
            window_width = event.width
            checked_size = None

            for min_size in self.size_dict:
                delta = window_width - min_size
                if delta >= 0:
                    checked_size = min_size

            if checked_size != self.current_min_size:
                self.current_min_size = checked_size
                self.size_dict[self.current_min_size]()

    def create_small_layout(self):
        print('Hello')

    def create_medium_layout(self):
        print('Medium layout created')

    def createLargeLayout(self):
        print('Large Layout Created')
````

I've checked the documentation for customTkinter, and it doesn't seem to have built-in support for responsive layouts using 'SizeNotifier.' How can I implement responsive layouts in my customTkinter application without 'SizeNotifier'?

I've already tried [mention any approaches or solutions you've attempted], but I'm still facing this issue.

Any guidance or suggestions on how to achieve responsiveness in customTkinter would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are describing appears to be nothing to do with customTkinter but more to do with this part of your code:

```py
            self.sizeNotifier = SizeNotifier(
                self,
                {
                    300: self.sizeNotifier.create_small_layout(),
                    600: self.sizeNotifier.create_medium_layout(),
                    1200: self.sizeNotifier.createLargeLayout()
                }
            )
```

More specifically, the problem is in the line `self.sizeNotifier.create_small_layout()` and the equivalent lines for the medium and large layouts. You are attempting to call the methods on `self.sizeNotifier` before `self.sizeNotifier` has been assigned a value.

Python can only assign a value to `self.sizeNotifier` once a `SizeNotifier` object has been created. However, before it can do that, it needs to evaluate all of the arguments it needs to call `SizeNotifier(...)` with. So at the point
Python tries to run `self.sizeNotifier.create_small_layout()`, `self.sizeNotifier` hasn't been set. Hence you get the AttributeError you are describing.

To fix the problem, you could declare `create_small_layout()` as a `@staticmethod`:

```py
   @staticmethod
   def create_small_layout():    # note, no 'self' here.
       print('Hello')
```

and change `self.sizeNotifier.create_small_layout()` to `SizeNotifier.create_small_layout()`.

Alternatively, you could move this method outside of your class and just have it as a top-level function:

```py
def create_small_layout():
    print('Hello')
```

In this situation, you'd change `self.sizeNotifier.create_small_layout()` to just `create_small_layout()`.

For brevity, I only considered the `create_small_layout()` method. In reality, you'd do exactly the same for the methods that create a medium or a large layout as well.